# Unfloated block unexpectedly clears floated block in IE6/IE7

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I've been banging my head on the Internet Explorer bug lists and I don't see one corresponding to this behavior. Is it a known issue? If so, what is it called and is there a hack to fix it?

The problem: when I float blocks to the left, unfloated blocks to the right (i.e., still in the "flow") are unexpectedly moving down to clear the floated blocks. I see the problem only in IE6 and IE7.

In this example, paragraph 5 should be immediately under paragraph 3 and to the right of paragraph 2. Instead it moves down to clear paragraph 2.

Screenshots: http://prentissriddle.com/tmp/tmp-float.gif

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p { border: 1px solid #000; font-family: sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Paragraph 1: unfloated.</p>
<p style="float: left; clear: left; width: 150px;">Paragraph 2: floats left. a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
<p>Paragraph 3: unfloated.</p>
<p style="float: left; clear: left; width: 150px;">Paragraph 4: floats left. a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
<p>Paragraph 5: unfloated.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a known bug? Is there a fix? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried applying a width to the unfloated paragraphs?

Comment: Ben, thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and it made no difference in the vertical spacing of the unfloated paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 / 7 float bugs are nightmares best avoided. Is there any way that you can achieve the layout that you want using techniques other than relying on clear: left and floated elements? I tested out your code using all of the IE float-fixing tricks that I can think of off the top of my head (zoom: 1, height: 1%, explicitly setting widths, margin-left: on the unfloated blocks, various display: settings, the usual suggestions from Position Is Everything...), but couldn't find something that would make IE6/7 line up properly vertically. What a pain!

I know this is likely highly simplified dummy code, but I did find that you can make things appear consistent if you switch the source order around and specify a consistent margin + padding for all of the paragraphs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        p { border: 1px solid #000; font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Paragraph 1: unfloated.</p>
    <p style="float: left; clear: left; width: 150px;">Paragraph 2: floats left. a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3: unfloated.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 5: unfloated.</p>
    <p style="float: left; clear: left; width: 150px;">Paragraph 4: floats left. a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam. At least now I know I'm not crazy.  
  
The use case I have in mind won't let me shuffle the order of the blocks: I want to let Wordpress users create pull quotes that get floated left into an otherwise blank sidebar (probably using a shortcode like [pullquote] [/pullquote]). They would expect to compose their text in its natural order.

Comment: I already had to squash another Explorer bug to get this far: IE6/IE7 blows up if a negative margin-left isn't smaller than the floated object. The fix was to cheat by one pixel and hope no one noticed. :-(

Comment: Ah, I see. Just to play devil's advocate, if you were to have the pull quote come first in the source order, it'd likely simplify most of the float issues. One good example of this usage might be Liz Danzico's Bobulate blog's side notes (http://bobulate.com/post/5013829096/the-social-life-of-marginalia) -- they're just div's floated left with a set width of 160px, and the paragraphs of the page all have margin-left: 180px, and IE7 at least seems cool with that.

Comment: Adam, there are lots of ways to skin a cat. Bobulate avoids putting a negative left margin on the pull quotes by putting a large positive left margin on the unfloated paragraphs. My preference is to wrap the main content in a <div> and apply a margin to that rather than trying to anticipate every kind of item that might appear in it and give them all their own fat left margins. In theory that seems like the more robust solution. But I guess IE is telling me that my preference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down an "answer" (at least for IE7, I could not test IE6) on this site: http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWfc2.html (Case 4 which solved your situation, Case 2). I say "answer," because it does require some extra html code and css that is worthless otherwise. If there is a way to detect the browser and only enter it if needed, that might be best. The key was to introduce another floated element before the element that had both `float` and `clear` on it. Here is a modified version of your code:

HTML

```
<p>Paragraph 1: unfloated.</p>
<p class="floated">Paragraph 2: floats left. a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
<p>Paragraph 3: unfloated.</p><span class="floatFix"></span>
<p class="floated">Paragraph 4: floats left. a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z</p>
<p>Paragraph 5: unfloated.</p><span class="floatFix"></span>
```

CSS

```
p { border: 1px solid #000; font-family: sans-serif; }
.floated {float: left; clear: left; width: 150px;}
.floatFix {float: left; width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```